# Junos custom-attack signature pattern syntax

Tags: security, configuration, junos

I am stuck at a point with the configuration of a custom-attack signature in Junos. According to the [Junos Custom Attack Definition documentation page](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-security/junos-security10.0/junos-security-swconfig-security/idp-understand-custom-attack.html#idp-understand-custom-attack), I can set up a custom attack based upon a signature in the packet. In the documentation you can specify a "pattern" to match, but it fails to describe what the pattern syntax should be. Particularly, I want to match the HEX values of

> 8C 00 13 00

in the first four bytes of the TCP data payload. Does anyone know how to accomplish this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at other patterns on the defaul attack objects whit the command

`show log /var/db/idpd/sec-download/SignatureUpdate.xml`

here are a few exadecimal examples:

`<Pattern><![CDATA[.*\xeb 2c 5b 89 d9 80 c1 06 39 d9 7c 07 80 01\x.*]]></Pattern>

<Pattern><![CDATA[.*\xffff ff2f 4249 4e2f 5348 00\x.*]]></Pattern>

<Pattern><![CDATA[.*\x7FFF FB78 7FFF FB78 7FFF FB78 7FFF FB78\x.*\x408A FFC8 4082 FFD8 3B36 FE03 3B76 FE02\x.*]]></Pattern>

<Pattern><![CDATA[.*\xeb23 5e33 c088 46fa 8946 f589 36\x.*]]></Pattern>`

so your pattern shoul be:

`<Pattern><![CDATA[.*\x8C 00 13 00\x.*]]></Pattern>`

Comment: Where you able to solve your problem?